# How do I handle the app termination when I want to close a socket?

Tags: android, sockets, application-lifecycle

Suppose I have three activities A,B, and C. These activities all use a socket connection to receive data. The socket connection is a Telnet connection, so it can't be closed and reconnected arbitrarily.

If the current back stack is A > B > C, `Activity A` may be destroyed by Android, so I can't close the socket in `onDestroy()` method, otherwise `Activity C` would not be able to receive data from the socket.

I want to close the socket when the app is terminated. I can manually close it when I press the BACK on the root activity. However, if the app is killed when it is on the background, how do I handle this situation to close the socket and release related resource?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would recommend you use only one `Activity`/task to communicate. All others should use the `CommunicationManager`. Also remember that `onDestroy` does not always get called. Use `onPause` on your start/end - for Activities - to be sure that you end all your stuff in an well organized and secure way.

Basically I would create an asynchronous background task that handles the communication so your UI does not get blocked.